# Upgrading Selenium from 2.x.x to Selenium 4:package com.thoughtworks.selenium.webdriven does not exist

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Can someone please help me fix errors while upgrading selenium 2.x.x to Selenium 4 in the Maven project.
I am mostly getting errors as :
package com.thoughtworks.selenium.webdriven does not exist

Please help me with a complete step to step guide to upgrade selenium.

TIA

Comment: How are you upgrading? Using _standalone jar_, _client jars_ or _maven_

Comment: It's a maven project and I changed the selenium version in the pom file.